# Why does CommandLineToArgvW treat its first argument differently?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, command-line

Why is it that the following lines don't print the same thing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <shellapi.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    fwprintf(stderr, L"%s\n", CommandLineToArgvW(  L"\"C:\\\\\" b", &n)[0]);
    fwprintf(stderr, L"%s\n", CommandLineToArgvW(L"a \"C:\\\\\" b", &n)[1]);
}
```

The outputs are:

```
C:\\
C:\
```

but I'd have assumed they should print the same number of backslashes.

Comment: From the Microsoft [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) reference: "`CommandLineToArgvW` has a special interpretation of backslash characters when they are followed by a quotation mark character ("). This interpretation assumes that any preceding argument is a valid file system path, or else it may ***behave unpredictably***" (emphasis mine). Since the slashes aren't a valid file system path, *behaving unpredictably* is what you could expect from the function.

Comment: will be more revealing for example use "\"\\\\\" \"\\\\\" \"\\\\\"" -  (output \\ \ \ )so `CommandLineToArgvW` for the 0(first) token  use another parsing rules

Comment: The first word of the command line is the program name, and backslashes in the program name are literal, not doubled.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thanks! Is that documented somewhere or just something I'm supposed to know? Are there other quirks like this?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I could've made it a valid path and the question would've still been there.

Comment: Then please do. The less unrelated problems you have in your [mcve] the less we have to distract us from the real problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Done. Hopefully less distracted now?

Comment: `C:\\\` is not a valid path. CommandLineToArgvW is designed for parsing command lines. Don't use it as a general-purpose parser. That's not what it's for.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Oh it definitely is a valid path. Try `CreateFile(TEXT("C:\\\\"), FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL)`.

Comment: As I noted, the first word on the command line is the path to the program, and paths are quoted but not double-backslashed. A possible command line is `"\\server\share\program.exe" args` and you want this to parse as argv[0] = `\\server\share\program.exe` and not `\server\share\program.exe`. Look at it through the eyes of the intended usage pattern, not through some abstract set of rules.

Comment: @RaymondChen: The thing is I don't always have the first word on the command line, sometimes I only have the rest. Like when the caller says "pass `--foo=C:\\ --bar` to your sub-program", I need to be able to parse it. And this function looked like exactly the right tool for the job, until I found this quirk.

Comment: If it's not formatted as a command line, then don't use CommandLineToArgvW. You can do your own parsing, or you can format it as a command line (by putting a dummy program name in front, say).

Comment: @RaymondChen: I mean, it _is_ formatted as a command line, the first argument just doesn't happen to be a program name. And it doesn't have to. That's just an arbitrary requirement you made up, but it's not true. You can pass pretty much anything as the first argument... you know this better than me. And programs are perfectly right to use that information as input to decide what to do, just like BusyBox does on UNIX. I mean now that I know the issue is there I can work around it by adding a dummy prefix, but how do I know there aren't other quirks lying around? Was there a way for me to know?

Comment: The first word on the command line is parsed as a quoted program name, because that's how GetCommandLine works. Sorry you don't like that.